# Re order list items jquery

Tags: jquery

Without using scrollable - I am trying to use a 'click' to move (nested) ul's up or down. However in this example: console.log = [] ? I know its ugly and Im probably not going to use it but I was more interested in why I cant get and result for 'prevList'?

```
$(function(){
$('.moveUp').click(function(){
    theList = $(this).parent().parent();        
    prevList = $(this).parent().parent().prev();
    console.log(prevList);              
        });
});



<ul>
<li>

<div class="category-list">
<ul>
<li>Category: other</li>
<li>Edit this Category</li>
<li>Delete this Category</li>
<li class="moveUp">Move up</li>
<li class="moveDown">Move down</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="category-list">
<ul>
<li>Category: other</li>
<li>Edit this Category</li>
<li>Delete this Category</li>
<li class="moveUp">Move up</li>
<li class="moveDown">Move down</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="category-list">
<ul>
<li>Category: other</li>
<li>Edit this Category</li>
<li>Delete this Category</li>
<li class="moveUp">Move up</li>
<li class="moveDown">Move down</li>
</ul>
</div>

</li>

<li>Some other List Item</li>

<li>Ditto</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The upper list has no `prev`.  The other lists seem to work fine and the console shows that it gets the previous div.  `prev` does not wrap around, so if the element is the first child then it does not get anything.

Comment: sorry - I knew the upper list wouldnt get anything!  I didnt realise that prev doesnt wrap around  - thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works if you give .category-list divs and uls an id

```
$('.moveUp').click(function(){

    var theList = $(this).parent(); 
    var theListparentId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');     
    var prevList = $(this).parent().parent().prev().children();
    var prevListparentId = $(this).parent().parent().prev().attr('id');

    if(prevListparentId !== undefined){

        $('#'+prevListparentId).html(theList);
        $('#'+theListparentId).html(prevList);

      } else {

        alert('No previous');

      }              
    });

$('.moveDown').click(function(){

    var theList = $(this).parent(); 
    var theListparentId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');        
    var nextList = $(this).parent().parent().next().children();
    var nextListparentId =$(this).parent().parent().next().attr('id');

    if(nextListparentId !== undefined){

        $('#'+nextListparentId).html(theList);
        $('#'+theListparentId).html(nextList); 

     } else {

        alert('No next');

     }
   });
});
```

As Kingjiv noted your not getting a result for 'prevList' if there isn't one i.e `prevListparentId !== undefined`